# Split columns to few variables and move corresponding value to new column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this (with many more rows):

```
   id act_l_n pas_l_n act_q_p pas_q_p act_l_p pas_l_p act_q_n pas_q_n
    1      14       8      14      10      21      11      21      11
    2      19       9      11      17      22      11      20      11
```

Every column name contains information about 3 variables separated by '_' (each has 2 levels named act/pas, l/q, n/p). Values are scores corresponding to each combination of variables (i.e. 1 of 8 conditions).

I need to move 3 variables to 3 separate columns, mark their levels by digits, and move corresponding value to separate column called "score". So from 1st row of current data frame I'd get something like this:

```
id  score   actpas lq   pn
1   14       1     1    1
1   8        2     1    1
1   14       1     2    2
1   10       2     2    2
1   21       1     1    2
1   11       2     1    2
1   21       1     2    1
1   11       2     2    1
```

I've  tried wrangling this with dplyr using gather and separate functions, but I can't really get what I need. Help with dplyr would be most appriciated!

Comment: could you edit the question to make it more understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand well:

```
df<-read.table(textConnection(
"id,act_l_n,pas_l_n,act_q_p,pas_q_p,act_l_p,pas_l_p,act_q_n,pas_q_n
1,14,8,14,10,21,11,21,11
2,19,9,11,17,22,11,20,11"),
header=TRUE,sep=",")

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
gather(df,k,score,-id) %>% mutate(v1=1+as.integer(substr(k,1,3)=="pas")
                                 ,v2=1+as.integer(substr(k,5,5)=="q")
                                 ,v3=1+as.integer(substr(k,7,7)=="p")) %>%
  select(-2) %>% arrange(id)
#   id score v1 v2 v3
#1   1    14  1  1  1
#2   1     8  2  1  1
#3   1    14  1  2  2
#4   1    10  2  2  2
#5   1    21  1  1  2
#6   1    11  2  1  2
#7   1    21  1  2  1
#8   1    11  2  2  1
#9   2    19  1  1  1
#10  2     9  2  1  1
#11  2    11  1  2  2
#12  2    17  2  2  2
#13  2    22  1  1  2
#14  2    11  2  1  2
#15  2    20  1  2  1
#16  2    11  2  2  1
```